# Using pytorch, how to write a jacobian matrix in the loss function？

Tags: python, pytorch

In knowledge distillation，we usually use Jacobian matching like this：[T and S are the logits produced by the teacher network and student network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnr1q.jpg)

Thank you very much！

Comment: Have you tried doing `backward` on the difference of the logits?

Comment: @akshayk07 Sorry, I haven't